# Background image isn't changing

Tags: javascript, html, background-image

I'm trying to get a random background image. But when I load the page my background is empty.
This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        function random_imglink(){
            var myimages=new Array();
            myimages[1]="images/1.png";
            myimages[2]="images/2.png";
            myimages[3]="images/3.png";
            myimages[4]="images/4.png";
            var count=Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length);
            if (count==0){
                count=1;
            }
            document.write("'" + myimages[count] + "'");
        }
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
    </head>

    <body background=random_imglink()>
        <?php include ("header.php"); ?>
        <div align="center" >
            <?php include ("main.php"); ?>
            <?php include ("footer.php"); ?>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope someone has got a solution to this problem?

Comment: `if (count==0){count=1;}` - just `count++`

Comment: Also it't better to use `return` instead of `document.write()` Here is nice page about using `document.write` http://www.sophox.com/wordpress/?p=551

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this inside your script tag:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var imgs = [
        'images/1.png',
        'images/2.png',
        'images/3.png',
        'images/4.png'
    ];
    document.body.style.background = 'url(' + imgs[Math.round(Math.random() * (imgs.length - 1))] + ')';
}
```

[How to set background in css](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)

Don't forget to check if the images really exist.

Comment: You're wellcome, don't forget to press the up button :)

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation. Will come back to vote up when I can.

Comment: The solutions seems to work with Firefox. But when I try IE or Chrome it still seems to be blank. Is there any reason for that? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Johannes, I improved a bit the code, may be you received the value "4" as a random number, which can not be an index, I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/B5bjs/ , tested in Chrome, works, in IE can't test, I'm on Linux

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
var myimages=new Array();
myimages[1]="images/1.png";
myimages[2]="images/2.png";
myimages[3]="images/3.png";
myimages[4]="images/4.png";
var count=Math.floor(Math.random() * myimages.length);

if (count==0){
count=1;}
document.body.style.backgroundImage="url('" + myimages[count] + "')";
}

</script>
```